# In Python, are functions called after a return statement?

Tags: python, recursion, return

When using recursive functions, is the function called right after the return statement, or when it has been returned?

i.e
 " Use a recursive algorithm to find the factorial of an integer."

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else: 
        return n * fact(n-1)

fact(5)
```

I want to correctly visualize when the fact scopes are made.
Is the first return statement, n * fact(n-1), executed if after it has been 
properly evaluated?
Or is n * fact(n-1) called upon in the global scope, after it has been returned?

Comment: Have you looked at evaluation order in the python docs?

Comment: Conceptually the function result  is evaluated first before anything is returned. You can confidently use this fact to build your understanding. The implementation details of how this occurs may vary across different Python versions.

Comment: Thanks Rick Teachey, does this mean that the evaluation generates nested scopes? By the way, I had difficulties finding the documentation on evaluation order in python. Do you have any suggestions/key words?

Comment: If the expression to the right of `return` would be evaluated in the namespace of the caller (one up the stack), then you could never be able to return anything from the namespace of the function.

Comment: Yes, nested scopes. There is a recursion limit though. Maybe Python recursion limit would be a good search term.

Comment: Although to be clear, "nested scopes" might lead to more confusion than clarity. It's really just thousands of independent namespaces.